# IBM BPM Instances failing with 'Variable map hasn't been loaded yet'. anyone else has faced this?

Tags: pivot-table, ibm-bpm

```
IBM BPM 8.0.1 instances are failing with the following error trace
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.quartz.DbNotificationBpdTask.doWithLock(DbNotificationBpdTask.java:47)java.lang.IllegalStateException: Variable map hasn't been loaded yet
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.core.pse.impl.PivotTableUtils.getVarMap(PivotTableUtils.java:270)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.core.pse.impl.PivotTableUtils.getColumnNameFromMap(PivotTableUtils.java:306)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.core.pse.impl.PivotTableUtils.pivotColumnNameFromAlias(PivotTableUtils.java:140)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.core.pse.impl.PivotTableUtils.pivotColumnNameFromAlias(PivotTableUtils.java:102)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.BPDInstanceDAO.updatePivotTable(BPDInstanceDAO.java:699)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.BPDInstanceDAO.saveSearchableValues(BPDInstanceDAO.java:665)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.BPDInstanceDAO.save(BPDInstanceDAO.java:284)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.quartz.AbstractNotificationBpdTask.doWithLock(AbstractNotificationBpdTask.java:55)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.quartz.DbNotificationBpdTask.doWithLock(DbNotificationBpdTask.java:47)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.quartz.AbstractBpdTask$1.doExecuteDuringLock(AbstractBpdTask.java:92)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.quartz.AbstractBpdTask$1.doExecuteDuringLock(AbstractBpdTask.java:82)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.util.LockBPDInstanceCommand$1.doInTransaction(LockBPDInstanceCommand.java:62)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.core.TXCommand$2.call(TXCommand.java:79)
    at com.lombardisoftware.utility.spring.ProgrammaticTransactionSupport.executeInExistingTransaction(ProgrammaticTransactionSupport.java:557)
    at com.lombardisoftware.utility.spring.ProgrammaticTransactionSupport.execute(ProgrammaticTransactionSupport.java:287)
    at com.lombardisoftware.server.core.TXCommand.executeInDeadlockRetryLoop(TXCommand.java:77)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.util.LockBPDInstanceCommand.execute(LockBPDInstanceCommand.java:74)
    at com.lombardisoftware.bpd.runtime.engine.quartz.AbstractBpdTask$2..
```

we are using Pivot tables for saved search optimization... Please help

Comment: When are they failing? During creation? When entering a specific task?

Answer (score 0):

[Drop and re-create the pivot tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.admin.doc/topics/ctuningtools.html?cp=SSFPJS_8.5.5&lang=en).  There is no data loss for doing this.  more than likely a new version application (snapshot) was installed or one was archived or deleted, which caused a this to happen.